# Command-line options in python programs

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments

I know how to use command-line arguments in python (2) using sys.argv, but is there also a way to have bash-like options for the program? (for example `myprogram --help`)

Comment: [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Sorry if it is an obvious and stupid question, but I'm a newb.

Comment: @MadTux - I don't think the downvotes have anything to do with that.  Most likely, they came as a result of not showing any research effort or attempts to solve this problem yourself.  Downvoting for a noob, but properly constructed question is against the spirit of this site.

Comment: I tried, and even came across argparse, but thought it was not for options :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a built in library for that called argparse.

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

and a tutorial for it

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Answer (score 3):

Python 3: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Python 2.7: http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Python 2.6 and below: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/optparse.html

The above libraries do (unless told otherwise) automatically generate `--help` for you based on given parameters to the argument parser.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy enough to do manually:

```
for a in sys.argv[1:]:
    if a.startswith("-"):
        if a == "--help":
            do_help()
        else:
            do_usage()
    else:
        # handle command line arg
```

While there are libraries like `argparse` that exist to do some of this work for you, it's worth knowing that the underlying concepts are super easy.

Comment: Are they 'special' in any, though? Or are they just usual arguments with a '-' or '--'?

Comment: Nothing special. `sys.argv` is just space-separated words.

Comment: I like this way best, because it plays nicely with static analyzers like pylint.